# Tried to mv folder, now having trouble finding folder

Tags: ubuntu, find, mv

Yeah, so I was trying to move a folder around, and now I'm having trouble finding it.

Originally it was in my `.../Downloads/` directory.

I did: `sudo mv Downloads/Blah/ ~/` ... which seemed to work fine.

Then I realized that the folder I moved was using other files from the `Downloads` directory, so I tried to move it back.

I did: `sudo mv Blah/ /Downloads/` ... I note that I probably should have typed `Downloads/` rather than `/Downloads/`.

Now, I can't find the folder "Blah". I tried `ls` in `Downloads`, to no luck.

I have also tried `sudo find / -name Blah -type d` and other variations of the `find` command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a `/Downloads` folder before?  Because most likely, now your `Blah` directory *is* `/Downloads`.

In the future, you probably should avoid using `sudo` for these types of operations.  They're all inside your own directory, you shouldn't need to use it at all.

Comment: Yes, the `/Downloads` folder existed... it's where I originally moved `Blah` out of (to home directory). So now the contents of `/Downloads` have been removed in place of `Blah`?

Comment: So, when you say `.../Downloads/` you mean `/Downloads/`?

Comment: Sorry for ignorance. I mean `user$/Downloads/`.

Comment: @d0rmLife you *renamed* `~/blah` to `/Downloads` which is **a directory in the root dir of the filesystem `/`** instead of in your home directory `~`

Comment: The contents of the old `~/Downloads/Blah/` should be inside `/Downloads/`, if it was indeed renamed as steeldriver said.

Comment: So would `mv /Downloads/ ~/` bring `Blah` back to my home directory? If so, would it overwrite my `user$/Downloads/` folder because of its new name?

Comment: No, it would put it into `~/Downloads/`, so you'd be left with `~/Downloads/Downloads/`.  Try running `sudo mv /Downloads ~/Blah` if that's what you want it named.  You need `sudo` here because you're modifying /.

Comment: Also, don't expect `user$/Downloads/` to actually work in Unix shells.  Either use `$USER` or `~` for your own user.  I don't know what `user$` is supposed to mean.

Comment: It was just a shorthand way of showing my user home directory. Anyways, the above command worked - thanks for the help!